# What is a good and pythonic way to differentiate between implicit and explicit imported components in a package)

Tags: python

I know about packages that differentiate between imported implicit components (via `import thepackage`) and explicit imported components (via 'import thepackage.explicte_component`).

I want to have this for my own package and wonder how this could be implemented in the folder and file structure of my package in a pythonic way. I can produce the expected behavior in my example here. **But the question** is if this is a good solution or if there is a better pythonic way for this.

Here is another real world example where `matplotlib.pyplot` is not usable until it is explicit imported.

```
Python 3.9.10 (tags/v3.9.10:f2f3f53, Jan 17 2022, 15:14:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\buhtzch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\__init__.py", line 222, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
>>> matplotlib.pyplot
<module 'matplotlib.pyplot' from 'C:\\Users\\buhtzch\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\pyplot.py'>
```

My own example currently looks like this

```
mypackage_prj
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── mypackage
│   │   ├── a.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── _mypackage.py
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   └── setup.py
└── tests
    └── ...
```

The simple `src/mypackage/__init__.py` only does `from ._mypackage import *`. The `src/mypackage/_mypackage.py` defines `foo()`. So I can do

```
import mypackage
mypackage.foo()
```

The submodule `src/mypackage/a.py` defines a `bar()`. This would throw an exeption because `a` is not imported yet.

```
import mypackage
mypackage.a.bar()
```

But this would work

```
import mypackage
import mypackage.a
mypackage.a.bar()
```

My current solution with the `_mypackage.py` file works for my self. But I have some side effects in my environment because of that "private" (?) py-file. For example [Sphinx has problems with filenames beginning with an underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71343831/4865723). It does not matter here that the Sphinx problem can be solved by an extra commandline switch. The point is that I assume that my solution is not good or standard because Sphinx can not handle it by default.

I want to overcome this workarounds and wondered if there is a better more pythonic standard way to do things like this.

Comment: So in your example you did the same `matplotlib` did. What's the point of the question then?

Comment: You reproduced the expected behavior, do you want to do as in matplotlib or do you want all the packages being available implicitely ?

Comment: I updated my question. Yes I can replicate that behavior. The question is if my solution is a good one or not. Is there a better and more pythonic way for that? And looking into the matplotlib repo it did not seems that they use my solution for this.

Comment: "For example Sphinx has problems with files like that and I have to workaround that with extra options in Sphinx." Which problems are you alluding to here? It seems your actual issue are these secondary problems, not the initial one that you already solved.